# Safe storing of auth token using .NET

Tags: .net, security, encryption

I'm currently working on desktop application which calls third party API. After authorizing against their "web service", a kind of user token is returned which should be stored locally (even if user closes application).

So I'm looking for solution to encrypt this token with user specific key. Does Windows (and .NET) provide some standard way for doing this? All I want is protect token from other users of same computer.

P.S. I can't store hash, as I need to decrypt this token at startup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah. Windows does provide it. Check out [DPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_protection_API) which can be accessed by .NET Framework's `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData` class (available since v2.0) to securely store sensitive information.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a number a built in functions for encryption in .NET, it all depends on exactly how you want to get it done.

Here is a [good beginning article](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/gsparamasivam/cryp04112005063256AM/cryp.aspx), that shows you some of the basic elements, classes, and methods of doing encryption in .NET

NOTE: all of the needed classes are in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace

Answer (score 0):

at runtime, you can store the auth key in a [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) ... to store it in between sessions you can use one of the [symmetric encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.aspx) APIs in the .NET framework.